# Which of the following rings are Principal Ideal Domains?

Tags: ring-theory

Which of the following rings are PID?

a) $\Bbb Z[x]$

b) $\Bbb Q[x] $

c) $(\Bbb Z/6 \Bbb Z)[x]$

d) $(\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z)[x]$

Comment: **Note:** $\Bbb F$ is a field $\iff $ $\Bbb F[x]$ is PID.

Comment: Which ones are you having trouble with? Remember that a PID is also (by definition) an integral domain. This will eliminate one of your possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

> $F$ is a field if and only if $F[x]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain

(For clarification, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214667/f-is-a-field-iff-fx-is-a-principal-ideal-domain) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356924/a-commutative-ring-a-is-a-field-iff-ax-is-a-pid))

So, b) and d) are correct

a) $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID since $<2,x>$ is not principal. see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500254/is-mathbbzx-a-principal-ideal-domain)

c) $\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}$ is even not an integral domain and so it is not a PID

Comment: It should be a comment !

Comment: @Surb No, comments are not for answers. They are for clarifications, and perhaps _very_ vague hints. This is just a c) away from being a full answer, so it is most decidedly _not_ fit to be a comment.

Comment: More is true, namely: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2363433/133781